# Keydown event stops triggering when I update HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a simple program that is built to teach you (me) how to write with the 8pen keyboard for Android.

On every keydown I check if the input value matches the "pattern-attribute" the html changes so that a new lesson comes up. This works fine. However when i update the keyup function stops triggering.

```
var lesson = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    new_lesson(lesson)
    lesson++
    //den här grejjen aktiverar inte på lektion 2
    $("input").keyup(function(event){
        var value = $(this).val();
        console.log(value)
        if (isValidInput ('input')) {
            new_lesson(lesson);
        }
    })
});

function isValidInput (input) {
    return $(input)[0].checkValidity();
}

function new_lesson(lesson_number){
    $('#form').html('<label>'+data[lesson_number]+'</label> <input type="text" pattern="'+data[lesson_number]+'"/>')
}
```

Why?

Comment: +1 for _that is built to teach you (me)_

Comment: For any future visitors with similair prolbems, the concept of binding really helped me. When document.ready, the .keyup is bound to every available input-field.

Comment: yes, this is a common issue and although there are many answered questions regarding this problem on SO, everyday similar questions are posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding an event registers the event handler directly to a DOM element, in your case `<input>`. As you are updating the `<input>` whenever a keyup occurs, the event is no longer registered to that new element.

Rather than using `.bind()`:

```
$("input").keyup(function(event){
```

Use `.on()` which works with all elements added to the page after the event is registered:

```
$("input").on("keyup", function(event){
```

See this [excellent post for the differences between .bind() and .on()](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your event was set to the last input in your html code, and you rewrite that part, so the event is lost also. you need to put the event setting in your new_lesson funciton.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you are replacing the html, you are creating a new instance of the input element, so the event handler goes away.

try `$('input').live('keyup',handler())`;

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$("input").keyup(function(event){
```

Use

```
$("input").live('keyup',function(){
```

The [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler attaches to types declared in the future too. Initially, when you used `.keyup`, it just attached the handler to your earlier defined input. On using `.live`, it attaches the handler to all the input elements which are already defined & are about to be defined in the future.

**EDIT:** As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (same usage as live)

Answer (score 1):

for dynamically generated elements you should delegate the events, you can use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, try the following:

> .on( events [, selector] [, data] , handler(eventObject) )

```
$("#form").on('keyup', 'input', (function(event){
    // ....
})
```